# Где можно подучить алгоритмы?

Tags: python, алгоритм, веб-программирование

Может есть какая-то книга по алгоритмам или курс?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что, вероятно, Ваш вопрос скоро закроют, я напишу ответ.

Конечно, кто то скажет, что я зря трачу время, но я могу посоветовать несколько очень хороших "мест".

1. Книга совсем начального уровня - "[Грокаем алгоритмы](https://junecat.ru/Storage/oth/grokaem_algoritmy.DJVU)" (автор - Бхаргава А). Очень запомниающееся название. Классификация и разбор примерно десятка наиболее "популярных" алгоритмов, начиная от сортировки и двоичного поиска, и заканчивая "жадными алгоритмами". Уровень - "для начинающих"
2. Есть перкрасные [записи лекций](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCu9NihyvsREyhR4c5tAy4FQ/videos) по алгоритмам, наверное, лучшие на русском языке. Это - курс лекций, которые публикуются фестивалем [RuCode](https://rucode.net/). Лекции не упорядочены, советую упорядочить по времени и "потоку" (C, D, E). Недостаток: лекции читаются разными авторами, в разном стиле. Уровень - для продвинутых. Кстатти, советую записаться на очередной фестиваль RuCode, неделя интенсивов даёт большой прирост знаний :-)
3. Есть "книжки для умных": прежде всего, это Т.Кормен, Ч.Лейзерсон, Р.Ривест, К.Штайн - Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ. Чтобы осознанно прочитать - придётся потратить... ну, от трех месяцев до года.
4. И огромное количество других источников! Начиная от лекций MIT, и заканчивая (не зря - именно заканчивая) сайтом https://e-maxx.ru/algo/ - здесь есть просто готовыен реализации, но Вам важно понимать, в какой момент какую из них нужно скорпировать и слегка исправить :-)

И еще один совет - не останавливаться на питоне, как языке, если Вы учите алгоримы. Алгоритмы тесно связаны со структурами даных, а структуры данных - с устройством памяти с вообще компьютера. Так что какой то язык со строгой статической типизацией был бы не лишним.

Можт бвыть, в комментариях кто то предложит и другие источники.